# Laravel Code Generator

Tags: php, laravel-4, crud

I come from CakePHP, recently started learning Laravel-4. It is very hard to see that such a great framework does not come with a code generator for basic CRUD operations. Is that a conscious decision or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty certain it was a conscious decision. However, Jeffrey Way has created a killer Generator package for Laravel:

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Comment: Great!! that is exactly what I was looking for. Looks good. I would however aks the original author why it did not generated the controller method body, as all the information is already known. May be the Generator is in its early stages and later version will have that.

Comment: Thanks. You could probably ask why or request features to Jeffrey himself. He's on twitter and runs the **awesome** Laravel tutorial site http://laracasts.com. He's a really nice guy.

Comment: Here is another killer package that allows you to generate all that code very easily https://github.com/CrestApps/laravel-code-generator and here is the doc https://crestapps.com/laravel-code-generator/docs/1.0

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.1 comes with artisan make command to generate different code files, following is a list:

```
Available commands for the "make" namespace:
  make:command     Create a new command class
  make:console     Create a new Artisan command
  make:controller  Create a new resource controller class
  make:event       Create a new event class
  make:job         Create a new job class
  make:listener    Create a new event listener class
  make:middleware  Create a new middleware class
  make:migration   Create a new migration file
  make:model       Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:policy      Create a new policy class
  make:provider    Create a new service provider class
  make:request     Create a new form request class
  make:seeder      Create a new seeder class
  make:test        Create a new test class
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a great package. Very flixable and generate complete and clean code.

https://packagist.org/packages/crestapps/laravel-code-generator

It has full documentation at http://crestapps.com/laravel-code-generator/docs/2.2

Here are YouTube screencasts to get you started https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkEd0nOoRf3o0ahspAu7Y9w/videos

Answer (score 2):

Here is one another package that I have created and which generates a API/CRUD via one single command.

https://github.com/mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try [Vemto](https://vemto.app) which is a Laravel Studio and Code Generator with a GUI

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [**Vemto**](https://vemto.app/) to generate all your APIs/CRUDs.

It is a very flexible generator that **generates clean and easy-to-read codes**.

Answer (score 0):

I also did a code generator that will read database table structure and create Laravel Models, Request, Controller and other assets according to that.

https://github.com/digitaldreams/laracrud